# 'temporary' login credentials when resetting password?

Tags: cakephp, passwords, cakephp-2.0, authentication

I am looking to build a "reset password" function in my CakePHP app, and reading around the net I have decided to:  Have the user type in their email address, send them an email with a link to http://www.mysite.com/users/reset_password/generated_uuid_that_expires_in_24_hours.  This will present a form that allows them to change their password. Obviously the hiccup is that I don't know how to log the user in with a temporary password.  Am I approaching this correctly?  I am thinking that the url I send them would be a hashed version of their email plus a uuid to use as a temp password, and that I would perform a user id lookup based on the email that comes in the url....but still, I wouldn't know how to manually log them in so they can change their password.

Comment: Why does the user need to be logged in to change their password? I can't think of many systems that do that - if you forget it, you're locked out until you do the reset process, enter a new password, and then login with that.

Comment: OIC.  I definitely like this approach.  I could conceivably let them change their password and then silently log them in afterwards for their convenience, couldn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the session approach.
after using the token from the email the user gets a

```
Tmp.User.id (as opposed to Auth.User.id)
```

in the session which will allow him to change the password.
afterwards it will be removed from the session again.

Comment: For all intents and purposes this user would be completely logged in as if I had used AuthComponent?  How well does this work if Acl is installed into the app?

Comment: you don't let them interfere! your action is public (in Auth->allow) and you deal with the logic in this controller action (disallow if no Tmp.User.id key is in the session) manually.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that.  Because I've used Auth, I've had no use for Sessions up to this point so should be interesting!  Thank you (BTW your Google Map Helper kicks serious butt!!!)

Comment: thx. BTW: the Auth component also relies on the session (the above Auth.User array) - that's where I got my idea for this temporary session approach.